# How to find root cause of effect with multiple distractors

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-network

I am writing an app to determine most likely cause of stomache-aches of users. Reducing the problem to its simplest form, for each user I have a multiple lists of ingredients that leads to his/her stomache-ache. For example, the first dish to cause a stomache-ache might have milk, eggs, peanuts. The second dish to cause a stomache-ache might have milk, eggs, lobster, and so on. How can I aggregate these lists of dish ingredients to determine the ingredient(s) most likely to be causing the stomach-ache? Alternatively, is there a way to generate a score/probability of each ingredient causing the stomach-ache? It seems like a simple Bayesian problem, or perhaps a machine learning/clustering problem, but I haven't quite been able to root down the specifics.

Comment: From what you wrote, this seems to be more statistics than math related. If so, have you considered asking at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/252490/john-omielan)? However, if there's more of a math element to it, please explain further what that might be. Thanks.

Comment: I only wrote Bayesian method because that's how I was trying to solve the problem. But I wondered (and was open to) if there was any other way to solve it, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I see you've posted basically the same question on Cross Validated at [How to find root cause of effect with multiple distractors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419284/how-to-find-root-cause-of-effect-with-multiple-distractors). In the future, please provide a link here as a courtesy to help avoid duplication of efforts. Thanks.